# Create folders based on substring of filename

Tags: powershell, loops, substring, directory

Attempting to get artist name from filename in a directory with 1,000+ MP3 files. I'm trying to use that substring to create directory to copy files into.

Filename format is "artistname - songtitle.mp3", the artist and title separated by " - " consistently, and they are all in the same directory.

Example:

```
Vic Damone - You And The Night And The Music.mp3
Sarah Vaughan - They Can't Take That Away From Me.mp3
...
```

I want to extract the artist name as a substring, which I can do with `Split("-")`, but do not know how to do this for 1,000+ files (all in the same directory).

I want to create new folders based on the name of the artist, then move all the files for that artist into correct folder.

So "Sarah Vaughan - They Can't Take That Away From Me.mp3" would be copied into a folder named "Sarah Vaughan".

Here is what I have had success with, 1 file at a time:

```
Set-Location -Path L:\   # This is where I have all the files

$file = (Get-ChildItem).BaseName     # get rid of the mp3 extension --- this works

$artist = $file.Split("-")[15].Trim  # trim will remove the trailing space --- this works (for the 15th element as an example)
```

I need a loop of some kind for every file in that directory, and some way to get the extracted artist name to become the name for a new directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem L:\ -Filter *.mp3 | ForEach-Object {
  # Extract the artist name from the file's base name.
  $artist = ($_.BaseName -split '-')[0].Trim()
  # Ensure that a subdirectory named for the artist exists
  # (creates it on demand; -Force ensures that the command is a no-op if
  # the subdir. already exists)
  $null = New-Item -Type Directory -Force $artist
  # Move the file at hand to the artist folder.
  Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $artist
}
```